# Copy files from one location to another without folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two folder a and b

a has files file1.txt and file2.txt

I want to copy all files from a folder to b.

I am using command:

```
cp -r a\ b\
```

but i am getting folder a inside b, all i want it just files file1.txt and file2.txt in folder b not folder a itself.

Comment: `cp -r a\* b\` should do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument(s) to `cp` are the file(s) to copy. You specified `a` so that's what it copied. To specify the files inside `a`, that's `a/*`

```sh
cp a/* b/
```

(Backslash as directory separator will vaguely work on Windows, but forward slash is absolutely preferable, and portable to saner platforms.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a tailor made problem for `rsync`, could you please try following. Pleade make sure you run this command where directory `a` is present, also when I tested my `a` and `b` directories were present in same directory OR you could change paths accordingly in your copy with absolute paths too.

```
rsync -avz a/ b/
```

By the way this will preserve permissions and time stamps of files from directory `a` to `b`. Plus this will help you incremental copy too later point to time, where `rsync` is intelligent enough to know that whatever file is present and did not change from last time it will NOT copy it again unlike `cp`.